# Can I construct a complete (as a Boolean algebra) saturated elementary extension of a given Boolean algbera?

Tags: logic, model-theory, boolean-algebra

I have been interested in the following problem:

> Let $B$ be an arbitrary Boolean algebra and $\kappa$ be an arbitrary cardinal.  Can one construct a $\kappa$-saturated $B^* \succ B$ that is complete, i.e., all joins and meets exist in $B^*$?

What are relevant sources for this problem?  I bet this problem appears in very old literature in model theory.  (I'm aware of Tarski's complete up-to-elementary-equivalence classification of Boolean algebras, but I'm not sure if that's very relevant.)

Comment: Any BA has a completion (the regular open algebra of its Stone space), but what do you mean by $\succ$? Or $\kappa$-saturated ?

Comment: Those are notation and a concept from model theory.  $\succ$ denotes elementary extension (see, e.g., http://modeltheory.wikia.com/wiki/Saturated_model);  for $\kappa$-saturation, see, e.g., http://modeltheory.wikia.com/wiki/Saturated_model .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $B$ is infinite and $\kappa$ is uncountable, then the answer is no. The reason is that every nontrivial instance of completeness is also an instance of non-saturation. For example, if $B$ is infinite, then it must have an infinite antichain $\langle a_n\mid n\in\omega\rangle$, by a theorem of Tarski. Suppose that $b=\bigvee_n a_n$ in $B^*$. Now consider the type $p(x,b,a_n)_n$ asserting that $x<b$ and that $a_n<x$ for each $n$. This type is consistent with the elementary diagram of $B^*$, but it is not realized in $B^*$, because $b$ is the join of the $a_n$. This type used countably many parameters, so it shows that if $B^*$ is $\sigma$-complete, then it is not $\sigma$-saturated.

Comment: Meanwhile, it seems to be interesting to consider how to find complete elementary extensions, apart from saturation. I think one will make use of the Tarski invariants.

Comment: Thank you for your splendid answer, and an idea for a different problem.  I have posted yet another variant of the problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2344673/20552).