# Can I construct a complete (as a Boolean algebra) $\aleph_0$ saturated elementary extension of a given Boolean algbera?

Tags: logic, reference-request, model-theory, boolean-algebra

This is a follow-up to [my previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2344364/20552):

> Let $B$ be an arbitrary Boolean algebra.  Can one construct a $\aleph_0$-saturated $B^* \succ B$ that is complete, i.e., all joins and meets exist in $B^*$?

For my previous question, which involved uncountable cardinal numbers instead of $\aleph_0$, [the answer is no](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2344562/20552). What happens we only need countable saturation instead?

Edit: This is also a [reference-request] post.

Comment: In the title of your question you write "countably saturated" but in the body you write "$\aleph_0$-saturated". In the usual terminology, countably saturated = $\aleph_1$-saturated. Please clarify by defining your terms.

Comment: @bof : According to his/her earlier post, OP means that parameters can be chosen in a set of cardinal $\aleph_0$ for the considered types.

Comment: No, he really does mean $\aleph_0$-saturated, that is, finitely many parameters in the type.

Comment: I have a feeling that every complete Boolean algebra is $\aleph_0$-saturated, using Tarski's elimination of quantifiers argument to show that types are not very expressive. In this case, the question becomes: does every Boolean algebra have an elementary extension that is complete?

Comment: For example, for the atomic case, see lemma 16 in my paper: http://jdh.hamkins.org/inclusion-relations-are-all-isomorphic/. One wants to extend that suitably to arbitrary Boolean algebras, in order to understand the limited expressivity of types with only finitely many parameters.

Comment: @JDH  Thank you for providing me with a link to your paper!  If one can complete and $\aleph_0$-saturate every atomic Boolean algebra, then that is already very interesting to me.  I haven't follow your language of mereology yet, but is your result in the paper equivalent to saying that the construction that I was interested in is always possible for the atomic case?

Comment: Yes, I believe that is right, and I think it works in general, using the Tarski elimination of quantifiers analysis in the general case. But it needs checking.  By the way, this question seems to be MathOverflow level.

Comment: @JDH I don't know very much about the policy / protocol regarding crossposting something to MathOverflow.  I'm not opposed to anybody starting a thread there.